# Changing colors of points using qqmath from the lattice package

Tags: r, colors, package, lattice

I have a plot that I made using qqmath in the Lattice package (I subset it to only 3 points to make it easier for an example).

```
table <- data.table(Col1=c(12,3,4), Col2 = c(54,4,6), Col3 = c("Pink", "Pink", "Red"))

PrbGrd <- qnorm(c(0.00001,0.0001,0.001,0.01, 0.05, 0.10,0.20,0.30,0.40, 
0.50, 0.60, 0.70,0.80,0.90,0.95,0.99,0.999,0.9999,0.99999))

PrbGrdL<-c("0.001","0.01","0.1","1","5","10","20","30","40","50","60","70","80","90","95","99","99.9","99.99","99.999")
PrbGrdL2<- c("99.999","99.99","99.9","99","95","90","80","70","60","50","40","30","20","10","5","1","0.1","0.01","0.001")


ValGrd<- c(seq(0.001,0.01,0.001),seq(0.01,0.1,0.01),seq(0.1,1,0.1),seq(1,10,1),seq(10,100,10),seq(100,1000,100),seq(1000,10000,1000))
ValGrd<- log10(ValGrd)
ValGrd2 <- c(-2:20)


ProbPlot <- qqmath(~ Col1, 
                data= table,
                distribution = function(p) qnorm(p),
                main = "Normal probability plot",
                pch=20,
                cex=0.5,
                xlab="Probability of Lower",
                ylab = "Pb",
                #xlim = c(max(PrbGrd),min(PrbGrd)),
                xlim = c(min(PrbGrd),max(PrbGrd)),
                scales=list(y=list(alternating=1),x = list(at = PrbGrd, labels = PrbGrdL, cex = 0.8)),
                #yscale.components=yscale.components.log10ticks,
                panel=function(x,...){
                  panel.abline(v=PrbGrd ,col="grey",lty=3)
                  panel.abline(h=ValGrd2,col="grey",lty=3)
                  panel.qqmath(x,distribution=qnorm)
                }
)
```

I would like to use the colors that are in the 3rd column of my table (Col3) to change the colors of the respective point on the plot. I can't figure out how to do it within qqmath, this would be simple with the regular plot function... but it doesn't seem as simple with qqmath.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated: based on OP's comment.

You can add the `col` argument, like:

```
ProbPlot <- qqmath(~ Col1, 
                data = table,
                distribution = function(p) qnorm(p),
                main = "Normal probability plot",
                pch = 20,
                cex = 0.5,
                xlab = "Probability of Lower",
                ylab = "Pb",
                #xlim = c(max(PrbGrd),min(PrbGrd)),
                xlim = c(min(PrbGrd),max(PrbGrd)),
                scales = list(y = list(alternating = 1),
                              x = list(at = PrbGrd,
                                       labels = PrbGrdL,
                                       cex = 0.8)),
                #yscale.components=yscale.components.log10ticks,
                panel = function(x, ...){
                  panel.abline(v = PrbGrd, 
                               col = "grey", 
                               lty = 3)
                  panel.abline(h = ValGrd2, 
                               col = "grey", 
                               lty = 3)
                  panel.qqmath(x,
                               distribution=qnorm,
                               col = table$Col3) # add colors for each point
                }
)
```

Comment: Aah, I commented out some code, because it didn't run. You just added it. I'll have a look and see what I can find.

Comment: I updated the answer. The problem was the `panel` parameter. `col = table$Col3` was in the wrong place.